# 3d viewport jquery problem when duplicated

Tags: jquery, html, css, 3d, parallax

**The problem only still excists in FF and Chrome. Hughes fixed it for IE**

I am currently working on a website where i use a Parallax effect to fake a 3D effect.
The script that i am using is `smart3d` (jQuery plugin).

The first slide that i made works fine (allthough the 100% width isnt actually 100% for some reason). If i duplicate it it shifts more to the right side when hovering. if i duplicate it again... it shifts even more.

I cannot find what the problem is so i decided to ask you guys for help.
You can view the problem here: http://basenharald.nl/3d/

I put the borders on the several `LI` items on so it becomes clearer what i mean.

hope you guys can help.

BTW: i get the same problem when i use `px` instead of `%` so that is not the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mailed the author and after a while he fixed it for me. The new download does not have this problem: http://4coder.info/en/code/jquery-plugins/smart3d/download/

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug in smart3d. It correctly adjusts for vertical scrolling, however it does not account for horizontal scrolling. I've found the relevant code, and here are instructions for how you can fix it.

Open up the file jquery.smart3d.js, and around line 69 you will find where we bind the mousemove function to the smart3d container:

```
thisObj.mousemove(function(e){
    if (settings['horizontal']) {
        var x = e.clientX - thisObj.offset().left;
        ...
```

What we need to do is account for horizontal scroll, just as it already does for the vertical scroll. Change the function to read:

```
thisObj.mousemove(function(e){
    if (settings['horizontal']) {
        var st = $('html').scrollLeft();
        var x = e.clientX - thisObj.offset().left + st;
        ...
```

Save the file and reload your page.

This *should* fix your problem, since it's the same way the script handles vertical offset. I haven't tried it myself though!

Comment: hmmm, 1 other question, since it seems you know this script. It is possible to set the first or last LI static. do you happen to know if it is possible to set another 1 static to? as you can see, my text moves on the website... same goes for the wall, i want those to be static. Do you happen to know how?

Comment: Yes actually :) When you create the smart3d object, use `$('#yourContainer').smart3d({ last_is_static: true });` (or `first_is_static`, that works too)

Comment: hmmm, befor i accepted this answer, but the problem still excists in firefox and chrome....

Comment: Could you maybe take another look at it. I reckon it should be simple to fix it for firefox and chrome, but i simply dont know how :)